# groupby method with filter functions and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

This the data set

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3','name4'],
                  'genre': ['sci-fci', 'action','comedy','action'],
                  'distributor': ['disney', 'disney','parmount','disney'],})
```

This is what , I did this but got an error

```
res=f.groupby(['Genre']).filter(["Distributor"]=='Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures')
```

I want to group by genre and only have movies launched by disney
eg want an output like  a table of disney has 1 sci-fic 2 action

Comment: what error? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[f['distributor'] == 'disney'].groupby(['genre']).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

This finds the rows with distributer equal to disney and groups the dataframe by genre

```
f = f[f['distributor'] == 'disney']
res = f.groupby(['genre'])
```

One line code could be

```
res = f[f['distributor'] == 'disney'].groupby(['genre'])
```